# Bootstrap.js is not loading in nopcommerce 3.10

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, popover, nopcommerce

I added bootstrap link in _Root.Head.cshtml page in nopcommerce. But my browser shows "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function" for following functions including boot strap. Please kindly assist me how I can enable boot strap and other functions.

```
Html.AppendCssFileParts("~/Content/jquery-ui-themes/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.10.0.custom.min.css");
    Html.AppendScriptParts("~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js");
    Html.AppendScriptParts("~/Scripts/public.ajaxcart.js");
    Html.AppendScriptParts("~/Scripts/public.common.js");
    Html.AppendScriptParts("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.0.min.js");
    Html.AppendScriptParts("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js");
    Html.AppendScriptParts("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js");
    Html.AppendScriptParts("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js");
    Html.AppendScriptParts("~/Scripts/js/bootstrap.js");
```

NOTE: Following images are four separated images.

[image: BootStrap not loading]
[image: Autocomplete]
[image: Nav on]
[image: Popover]

The Following is from browser source.
Note: Here bootstrap.js is loading before the jquery-1.7.1.min.js.

```
<link href="/Themes/DefaultClean/Content/globalstyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/Themes/DefaultClean/Content/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/Themes/DefaultClean/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/Themes/DefaultClean/Content/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/Content/jquery-ui-themes/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.10.0.custom.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <script src="/Scripts/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/public.common.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/public.ajaxcart.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/slimbox2.js"></script>
```

Comment: Are you scripts inside the @section Scripts {} section?

Comment: Thanks for your interest @Alundrathedreamwalker. Yes I placed these script in side @{} tags.

Comment: looks like you a re referencing your bootstrap.js twice.
you need to include only one reference to each of the css and js files

Comment: Sorry, that was a publish mistake. Now I corrected it. For your information I added new code of browser source. Here bootstrap is loading before the jquery. How can I make it load after jquery?

Comment: Are you using style bundles? if you are not sure check your shared layout

Comment: I am not sure about style bundles. The file I mentioned _Root.Head.cshtml is present in the shared folder only. I attached a reference image for you. please click the below link http://s5.postimg.org/rcqxcqs8n/shared.png

Comment: I think in nopcommerce the file is _Root.Head.cshtml  . You can open it and you will see the scripts and CSS references

Comment: Yes I already give the reference in _Root.Head.cshtml only, I mentioned it in the question itself. For your additional reference please go through the link http://postimg.org/image/q098auusz/

Answer (score 1):

NopCommerce's "AppendScriptParts" (it's an extension to the MVC Html object provided by NopCommerce) does not render scripts in the order they are added.

In fact, it's upside down. It adds each script part to the beginning of a list:

```
// excerpt from Nop.Web.Framework/UI/PageHeadBuilder.cs : AppendScriptParts
_scriptParts[location].Insert(0, new ScriptReferenceMeta
{
    ExcludeFromBundle = excludeFromBundle,
    Part = part
});
```

And renders them in order afterwards:

```
// excerpt from Nop.Web.Framework/UI/PageHeadBuilder.cs : GenerateScripts
var result = new StringBuilder();
foreach (var path in _scriptParts[location].Select(x => x.Part).Distinct())
{
    result.AppendFormat("<script src=\"{0}\" type=\"text/javascript\"></script>", urlHelper.Content(path));
    result.Append(Environment.NewLine);
}
return result.ToString();
```

You can add a call to `RenderScriptParts` for bootstrap.js before the other calls or you could always directly insert your  call for bootstrap.js in _Root.head.cshtml, under  `@Html.NopScripts(this.Url, ResourceLocation.Head)` call. You can use "~" in the script src attribute, too.

```
@Html.NopScripts(this.Url, ResourceLocation.Head)
<script src="~/Scripts/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

or

```
@Html.NopScripts(this.Url, ResourceLocation.Head)
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/js/bootstrap.js")"></script>
```

(use the first alternative in newer NopCommerce versions)